# Responsive jQuery doesn't work: Click below 768px width and hover above 768px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a menu to open when I am hovering over an li when above 768px window width, and it to open when I click the same li when below 768px window width. I keep having problems where the click, or hover, carries over between the two screen sizes (0-768px and 769 and up).

```
function colorChangeTest(width){
   if (width <= 767) {
      $('li').click(function() {
         $(this).toggleClass('colorChange');
      });
   } else {
      $('li').hover(function() {
         $(this).toggleClass('colorChange');
      });
   }
}

$(function () {
   var onLoadWidth = $(window).width();
   colorChangeTest(onLoadWidth);
   $(window).resize(function () {
      var resizeWidth = $(window).width();
      colorChangeTest(resizeWidth);
   });
})
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/bluebomber/jf26cjrc/)

What is the best way to do responsive jQuery that tell something it can be clicked, or hovered, depending on screen size, and determine this on page load and window resize?

Comment: for your question ... jQuery always uses selectors.. you can handle the event on selector. You always know what you invoke the event.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are saying

Answer (score 0):

FYI it is better to attach the same event listeners once in code to the same elements. In your case each time when window is resizing new event listeners (hover or click) are attached again and again.

Use `unbind` to aviod it. For example:

```
function colorChangeTest(width){
   var $li= $('li');
   $li.unbind();
   if (width <= 767) {
      $li.click(function() {
         $(this).toggleClass('colorChange');
      });
   } else {
      $li.hover(function() {
         $(this).toggleClass('colorChange');
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be working in myjsfiddle! Thanks so much, I'll integrate this into my full site and see how it goes!